# find limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I have a sequence:

$$ X_n\:=\:\cos\left(\left(\frac{3^n+\pi^n}{3^n+\left(\pi-\frac{1}{4} \right)^n} \right)^{1/n}\right) $$

I have to find the limit when $n \to \infty $ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Which is the best way to find the answer ? Can I reduce or use the Squeeze theorem in that case ?

Comment: Almost as a reflex, I'd go for Taylor expansions.

Comment: So far no one has up-voted the question among the five people who have who have answered it.

Comment: It seems as if the cosine is tacked on to the question as an afterthought. If one finds the limit of the expression inside the cosine function, then evaluating the cosine function at that point is a separate issue. (Although _a priori_ it's not inconceivable that the sequence inside the cosine function has a bunch of subsequential limits with in the set $\{a + 2\pi k: k\in\mathbb Z\},$ so the limit of that inside sequence would not exist but the limit of its cosine would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$${3^n+\pi^n\over3^n+(\pi-{1\over4})^n}=\left(\pi\over3\right)^n{1+\left(3\over\pi\right)^n\over1
+\left(\pi-{1\over4}\over3\right)^n}$$

Now $\pi-{1\over4}\lt3\lt\pi$, so $1+(3/\pi)^n\to1$ and $1+((\pi-{1\over4})/3)^n\to1$.  Thus

$$\left(3^n+\pi^n\over3^n+(\pi-{1\over4})^n\right)^{1/n}\to{\pi\over3}$$

Taking the cosine gives the limit $\cos(\pi/3)=1/2$.

Comment: My first step was going to be $$ \left( \frac{3^n+\pi^n}{3^n+\left(\pi-\frac{1}{4} \right)^n} \right)^{1/n} = \frac{ \left( 1 + \left( \frac \pi 3 \right)^n \right)^{1/n}}{\left( 1 + \left( \frac{4\pi-1}{12} \right)^n \right)^{1/n}}. $$ Maybe you've already done what I was going to do.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I thought it was a little more clear to pull the dominant terms out of the numerator and denominator, leaving stuff that tended to obvious limits.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: write your term as $$\cos\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^n}{1+\left(\frac{\pi-\frac{1}{4}}{3}\right)^n}\right)^{1/n}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac12$, because$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n+\pi^n}{3^n+\left(\pi-\frac14\right)^n}}$$behaves as$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{\pi^n}{3^n}},$$that is, as $\frac\pi3$, when $n$ is very large. And $\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Almost as a reflex, I'd go for Taylor expansions. (Because *it works.* Not always the most elegant, bu at least it gets us somewhere.) When $n\to\infty$, letting $x\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\pi -\frac{1}{4}}{3}$ and $y\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{3}{\pi}$, with $x>y$ (so that $y^n=o(x^n)$)

\begin{align}
\cos\left(\left(\frac{3^n+\pi ^n}{3^n+\left(\pi -\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{3}{\pi}\right)^n}{1+\left(\frac{\pi -\frac{1}{4}}{3}\right)^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\left(\left(1+y^n\right)\left(1+x^n + o(x^{n})\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\left(1+y^n + x^n +o(x^n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\left(1+x^n +o(x^n)\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right) \tag{as $x>y$}\\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+x^n +o(x^n)\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\exp\left(\frac{x^n}{n}+o\left(\frac{x^n}{n}\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\left(1+\frac{x^n}{n}+o\left(\frac{x^n}{n}\right)\right)\right) \\
&\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \cos\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Denote the argument of the cosine as $a_n$. Estimate:
$$\left( \frac{\pi ^n \left(\left(\frac{3}{\pi}\right)^n+1\right)}{2\cdot 3^n}\right)^{1/n}<a_n<\left(\frac{2\cdot \pi ^n}{3^n \left(1+\left(\frac{\pi -\frac14}{3}\right)^n\right)}\right)^{1/n}.$$
Taking limit:
$$\frac{\pi }{3}\le \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \le \frac{\pi}{3}.$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos{a_n} =\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n+ \pi^n}{3^n+ (\pi -1/4)^n}}\leq \sqrt[n]{\frac{2 \pi^n}{3^n}}=\sqrt[n]{2} \frac{\pi}{3} \to \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Also $$a_n=\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n+ \pi^n}{3^n+ (\pi -1/4)^n}} \geq \sqrt[n]{ \frac{\pi^n}{3^n+3^n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}} \frac{\pi}{3} \to \frac{\pi}{3}$$

So from squeeze theorem $a_n \to \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Now using the continuity of $\cos{x}$ we have that $$\cos{a_n} \to \cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}$$